# Convert Interop to ClosedXML

Tags: closedxml

I have 3 lines of C# Interop code that I am struggling to convert to ClosedXML. Can anyone please help?

```
str2 = worksheet.Range("B3", "L13").get_End(XlDirection.xlDown).get_Address(false, false, XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing).Replace("B", "L");
object[,] objArray = (object[,]) worksheet.Range("B3", str2).Value;
str3 = worksheet.Range("B3", "L13").get_End(XlDirection.xlDown).get_Address(false, false, XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing).Replace("B", "L");
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, could you provide actual and expected outputs, to help narrow down the issue ?

Comment: Hi @matthiasbe, 
The code is a bit complex that I can't understand what the actual and expected outputs of those specific lines are. I am trying to migrate a whole project from Interop to closedXML and only struggling with these couple of lines.
Thanks

Comment: I understand, the thing is it's hard to understand this piece of code out of its context. I would advise you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to have ideas

Answer (score 1):

As answered [here](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/1197)

This snipped looks overly complicated. First, you create a range from `B3` to `L13`, then move down to the last row (getting to `B13`, apparently), then replace `B` to `L` which gives you `L13` and finally you create a range `B3:L13` once more to get the values from there.

ClosedXML does not have a built-in method to convert a range into a two-dimensional array but this can be easily done manually:

```
var range = worksheet.Range("B3:L13");
var objArray = new object[range.ColumnCount(), range.RowCount()];
for (int i = 0; i < range.ColumnCount(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < range.RowCount(); j++)
    {
        objArray[i, j] = range.Cell(j+1, i+1).Value;
    }
}
```